# Use of undeclared identifier 'o'

Tags: c, cs50

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int height;
    {
        printf("Please select a height value between 1-23.");
        height = GetInt();

        while (height < 1 || height > 23)
        {
            printf("Height mustbe between 1-23, please choose new value.\n");
            height = GetInt();
        }
        {
            for (int n = 0; n < height; n++)

            for (int o = 0; o + n + 1 < height; o++)
            {
                printf(" ");
            }            
            for (int p = 0; p <= o; p++)
            {
                printf("#");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

//  I keep getting this error:

Use of undeclared identifier 'o'.
    for (int p = 0; p <= o; p++)
                         ^

I declared '0' in the line right above it, I cant seem to figure out why it's giving me this error.  Please help, I am VERY new to c and any insight is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "I declared '0' in the line right above it...". It looks like you are mixing `o` and `0` in the text of your own post. It is probably not a good idea to use `o` as a variable name, unless you are deliberately trying to obfuscate the code.

Answer (score 5):

```
    for (int o = 0; o + n + 1 < height; o++)
    {
        printf(" ");
    } 

    /* o is now out-of-scope */
```

The scope of identifier `o` stops after the `}`.

Comment: Probably also worth mentioning the suspicious-looking first `for`-loop, as it will probably not work as intended

Comment: @DrewMcGowen I'm under the impression that OP does not know what he is doing, that's why I'm answering strictly to what is being asked.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  This was helpful, like i said, I am VERY new to c and am really just getting my sea legs so to speak.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

Scope and lifetime of a variable declared in the header of a `for` cycle is limited to that `for` cycle. It does not exist outside that `for` cycle.

Answer (score 3):

**If the variable `o`is declared inside a `for` loop it will be `undefined` outside of that `for` loop.**
Declare the variable `o` outside of your loop, for example at the beginning of your function and your done.

---

**Here would be your fully debugged code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int height, o;
    {
        printf("Please select a height value between 1-23.");
        height = GetInt();

        while (height < 1 || height > 23)
        {
            printf("Height mustbe between 1-23, please choose new value.\n");
            height = GetInt();
        }
        {
            for (int n = 0; n < height; n++)

            for (o = 0; o + n + 1 < height; o++)
            {
                printf(" ");
            }            
            for (int p = 0; p <= o; p++)
            {
                printf("#");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you actually want is:

```
    for (int n = 0; n < height; n++)
    { // not actually necessary - but makes things much clearer.
        for (int o = 0; o + n + 1 < height; o++)
        {
            printf(" ");
            for (int p = 0; p <= o; p++)
            {
                printf("#");
            }
        }            
    }
```